# Can one add a virtual background with the latest version of Microsoft Teams on Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra (US version)?

Tags: privacy, background-process, microsoft-teams, samsung-galaxy-s-21, virtual-background

I read contradictory statements.

E.g.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/background-effect-on-samsung-s21/8ecfca7a-d025-47ee-9cb7-abcea99fa68f:

> Hi, I just got my new Samsung S21 phone and I'm surprised the background effect is not available on my teams app when I join a meeting. Does anyone has similar situation ?

vs. https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/01/28/galaxy-s21-users-can-apply-custom-backgrounds-and-snazz-up-video-calls-on-duo-zoom-teams-and-webex/:

> We've been able to confirm that these custom video effects are currently only available for four apps: Google Duo, Zoom, Microsoft Teams.

Can one add a virtual background with the latest version of Microsoft Teams on Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra (US version)?

Comment: Both statements can be true, considering the number of variants of "S21" that exists (4G, 5G, ... as 1st dimension) and (Qualcomm vs. Exynos as 2nd dimension). Therefore you have plenty of devices that may or may not support virtual background. Additionally the Teams app changes and potentially this feature was only active in certain app versions?

Comment: @Robert thanks I've made the question more precise.